# concurrency issues with granite ds , flex

Tags: apache-flex, graniteds

I use granite ds in my java server , but , when 100 user they're connected to flex application , granite return this error "Could not get channel id for message: flex.messaging.messages.RemotingMessage" 
Thank for the help.

Comment: There's a hundred reasons why this could happen.  You're not helping yourself by not helping us.  Can you show code?  How about some actual information?  Voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an error but just a warning issued by the AMF3Serializer class. It can happen, for example, when the server is sending data without explicitly using a declared channel.

You can safely ignore this warning: channel identification is only used in order to handle legacy (ie: old-fashion) serialization options (legacyCollection / legacyXMLDocument), see Adobe documentation about them [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=serialize_data_3.html) (the "Configuring AMF serialization on a channel" section).

It is very unlikely that you need to use these very specific serialization options. So, again, just ignore or disable this warning.